# anyone have an example of a remote Flash app login thru Services 3.x REST server?

Tags: services

I have a REST API implemented in Services 3.x. The API uses session authentication. A client wants to access the API from a remotely hosted Flash application. We've placed a crossdomain.xml in our docroot, enabling the client's app to communicate with us, but they are having troubles getting past login.

Anyone have any examples of a REST Login within Flash?